# Execute an SQL function only once

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a formula field that gets its value from an expression field (which executes an SQL scalar function) but I want to make sure this expression field is executed only once (the SQL function is passed a row value which is the same for all the rows in the recordset)

The way I see it, the formula field will end up calling the SQL function at every row being rendered in the report.

How would one do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value from the SQL function to a global variable in the report header and then reuse the value from that variable instead of referencing the SQL.

```
//{@Assign Value} - formula placed in report header
numbervar ExampleVar := {%SQL Expression};

//{@Use Value} - value can now be used anywhere in the report
numbervar ExampleVar;
...do something with ExampleVar
```

Comment: I am familiar with the formula workshop to write some of that code, but I can't find the section to type such code for the header. I am using (old) CR10.

Comment: They're just generic formula fields that can be placed anywhere in your report canvas regardless of section. Just create a formula field that declares and assigns the variable, then drag it onto your report header.